# Regular expression of a linux command: not equal to

Tags: regex, linux, command, find

In Linux, I want to find all files whose name is distinct from `myName`. I am trying to use a regular expression, but I doesn´t work:

```
find . -type f -name '*(?<!myName)*'
```

Where is my error?

Thanks.

Comment: `-name` does not accept a regular expression

Comment: And if it did (and used * to match any substring – I thought regex languages having `(?<!` were using `.*` for that), that regex would match anything, since any string is of the form “any string not followed by myName, followed by any string,” including “myName” itself – just let the first * match the letter m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
find . -type f ! -name '*myName*'
```